# Limit of data sent by API on Apache/PHP with Docker

Tags: php, docker, apache2, docker-compose

I have a very strange problem with Apache and PHP: I am trying to send some data formated as JSON to a very simple PHP script. The data is received as long as it does not go beyond 16Kb.
I am using the Docker container PHP7.1.11-apache although I have ran some test with other version with no more luck.

I have no error in Apache log files. The only thing I can see is that beyond 16Kb I receive an empty array, as if the data was wipped off.

The php script on the Apache/PHP container is as follow:

```
<?php
// Get data sent to this script
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

ob_start();
$headers = apache_request_headers();

// Display data sent
var_dump($data);
?>
```

The data is recorded into a text file and the value is repeated as to go below and beyond 16Kb:

```
{"data":"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA..."}
```

...and I send the content of this file using wget:

```
wget -O- --post-file="mydata.txt" --no-check-certificate https://myserver.loc/script.php
```

- The script has been sent using wget from outside but also inside the container to make sure it was not a problem with the Docker container.
- I've reviewed all Apache and PHP basic parameters also most of the parameters have well beyond 16Kb as a default value.

If anyone has any idea, I would really appreciate.

Thansk!

Comment: How much HDD space do you have available?

Comment: Hi Jay. There is more than 10 Gb available.